# page ranking in Php

Tags: php, mysql

I am using a small module in PHP CURL which reads company name/website from the my database, generates total 9 social ranks( Alexa,facebook,Google rank,Google hit,Yahoo,Bing,Twitter,Linkedin,Google plus) for a company using social API platform link, then finally generated rank is updated in the database. Per day 3000 data are been updated in database like Mysql.

I am looking for a better way to make the process faster and update up to minimum 50000 data per day. Is there any way to make the process faster or reduce the response time ?
Is there any way to convert those script in any other language like python for obtaining my target.

**Output of my script is like**

> Professionals{"Google_rank":0, "Google_hit":0, "Yahoo_hit":0,
>   "Bing_hit":0, "Alexa_rank":0, "Facebook_hit":0, "Twitter_hit":0,
>   "Linkedin_hit":1, "Googleplus_hit":0} Prue Jones Estate
>   Agents{"Google_rank":3 , "Google_hit":0, "Yahoo_hit":0, "Bing_hit":0,
>   "Alexa_rank":0, "Facebook_hit":0, "Twitter_hit":0, "Linkedin_hit":0,
>   "Googleplus_hit":0}

**my script code is here:**
index.php

```
<?php
ignore_user_abort(TRUE);
//(60 minutes * 24hrs * 2)=2days=172800
ini_set('max_execution_time', 580000); //300 seconds = 5 minutes
require("pagerank.php");
include('database.php');
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ (E_WARNING | E_NOTICE));
/*------ For China table -------*/
//$urlarray=mysql_query("select * from  amt_company_china_sample order by ID");
/*------ For Australia table -------*/
$urlarray=mysql_query("select * from  amt_company_aus order by company_key DESC limit 3939,2000");

echo "Updating the social rank score...<br>";
echo "Processing...<br>";
while($urlfetch=mysql_fetch_array($urlarray))
{
/*------ For China table -------*/
/*$companyid=$urlfetch['ID'];                   
$url=$urlfetch['WebSite'];
echo $urlname=$urlfetch['CompanyName'];*/
/*------ For Australia table -------*/
$companyid=$urlfetch['company_key'];                    
$url=$urlfetch['website'];
echo $urlname=$urlfetch['company_name'];
$pr = new PR();
if($url!="")
{
    $active=$pr->getcheckurl($url);
    $Google_rank=$pr->get_google_pagerank($url);
    $Google_hit=$pr->getIndexedPagesGoogle($url);
    $Yahoo_hit=$pr->getIndexedPagesYahoo($url);
    $Bing_hit=$pr->getIndexedPagesBing($url);
    $Alexa_rank=$pr->getAlexaRank1($url);
    $Facebook_hit=$pr->getIndexedPagesFacebook($url);
    $Twitter_hit=$pr->getIndexedPagesTwitter($url);
    $Linkedin_hit=$pr->getLinkedInShares($urlname);
    $Googleplus_hit=$pr->getGooglePlusOnes($url);
}
else
{
    $active=0;
    $Google_rank=0;
    $Google_hit=0;
    $Yahoo_hit=0;
    $Bing_hit=0;
    $Alexa_rank=0;
    $Facebook_hit=0;
    $Twitter_hit=0;
    $Linkedin_hit=$pr->getLinkedInShares($urlname);
    $Googleplus_hit=0;
}
echo $jsontext='{"Google_rank":'.$Google_rank.', "Google_hit":'.$Google_hit.', "Yahoo_hit":'.$Yahoo_hit.', "Bing_hit":'.$Bing_hit.', "Alexa_rank":'.$Alexa_rank.', "Facebook_hit":'.$Facebook_hit.', "Twitter_hit":'.$Twitter_hit.', "Linkedin_hit":'.$Linkedin_hit.', "Googleplus_hit":'.$Googleplus_hit.'}';

echo "<br>";
$amt_rank = 0;
$total_json_key=9;
$json_value=array($Google_rank,$Google_hit,$Yahoo_hit,$Bing_hit,$Alexa_rank,$Facebook_hit,$Twitter_hit,$Linkedin_hit,$Googleplus_hit);
for($i=0;$i<$total_json_key; $i++){
$value = $json_value[$i] == 0 ? 0.1 : $json_value[$i];
$amt_rank =  $amt_rank + (1/$value);
}

/*------ For China table -------*/
/*
$result = mysql_query("UPDATE amt_company_china_sample SET rank_json='$jsontext' WHERE ID= '$companyid'");
*/
/*------ For Australia table -------*/
$result = mysql_query("UPDATE amt_company_aus SET rank_json='$jsontext',is_active='$active',amt_rank='$amt_rank' WHERE company_key= '$companyid'");

}
echo "<br>update complete...";
?>

pagerank.php
?php
class PR {
    public function get_google_pagerank($url)
    {
        $query="http://toolbarqueries.google.com/tbr?client=navclient-auto&ch=".$this->CheckHash($this->HashURL($url)). "&features=Rank&q=info:".$url."&num=100&filter=0";
        $data=file_get_contents($query);
        $pos = strpos($data, "Rank_");
        if($pos === false)
        {
            $pagerank = "0";
            return $pagerank;
        } 
        else
        {
            $pagerank = substr($data, $pos + 9);
            return $pagerank;
        }
    }
    public function getIndexedPagesGoogle($url)
    {
        $query1 = 'http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=site%3A' . $url;
        $data=file_get_contents($query1);
        if (preg_match('#about ([0-9\,]+) results#i', $data, $p)) 
        {
            $hit=(int) str_replace(',', '', $p[1]);
            return $hit;
        }
            return 0;
   }//so on.........
```

Is there any solution to reduce time to collect those info or what kinds of change should i do for gaining my target.

Comment: How long does it take and do you need to do it at a specific time? You could set up a cron job that updates the xx oldest records every yy minutes.

Comment: You could look into `multi_curl()` to parallelize your outgoing requests 
(obviously subject to system memory constraints).  You are not currently using cURL anywhere even though you mention it in your post, so you would need to familiarize yourself with it.

Comment: Thanks for your response .. it take approx 7 -8 hours to complete .. @jeron

Comment: thanks @Mike Brant .. but i dont know about the cron job ..will u please tell  me about that things or give me some references where i can make my script efficient ...